# Error on route with parameter

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to have a name based login, so user name shows on login page.

My router:

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout',
loadingTemplate: 'loading',
waitOn: function(){ 
    return [Meteor.subscribe('userData')];
}
});

Router.map(function(){

this.route('publichome',{path: '/'});
this.route('register',{path: '/register'});
this.route('home',{
    path: '/:_name',
    data: function(){ 
        return {'name':this.params._name};
    }
});
this.route('login',{
    path: '/:_name/login',
    data: function(){
        Session.set('_name', this.params._name);
        return {'name':this.params._name};
    }
});
});

var requireLogin = function(pause){
console.log("Pedimos login");
var routeName = this.route.name;
if(!Meteor.userId()){
    this.redirect('/' + this.params._name + '/login');
    pause();
}
};

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: ['login','register','publichome']});
```

The route works, it shows the login page but data is never returned. It works if I login and try the same route.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the error:

I was publishing additional user data using:

```
Meteor.publish('userData'...
```

but when there's no user that publication is null and my WaitOn never ends. Fixed it adding:

```
this.ready();
```

before returning null on publication.